# Refund FOR loop not working properly

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm stuck with this Java homework question:

> Write a new method, Refund,  that simulates the refunding of any remaining credits in           multiples of 10 by repeatedly printing out the balance and decrementing by 10 each time until there is less than 10 credits remaining. Then begin decrement the balance by 1 credit repeatedly whilst printing to screen until the balance is zero. For example, if the current balance is 33 and Refund is called, the output to screen will look like this:
>
> Balance: 33 
>   Balance: 23 
>   Balance: 13 
>   Balance: 3 
>   Balance: 2 
>   Balance: 1 
>   Balance: 0

It works perfectly fine with any number except numbers ending in '0' i.e. 10,30,100 etc.

Here's my Refund method:

```
public void Refund(){
    System.out.println("You have selected the refund option:");

    for(int counter=(int)balance;counter>=10;counter-=10){
        System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
        balance-=10;
    }

    for(int counter=(int)balance;counter>0;counter-=1){
        System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
        balance-=1;
    }

    System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
}
```

Basically, the only way I can make it work with 10,30 etc. numbers is to do

```
for(int counter=(int)balance-10;counter>=10;counter-=10){
```

in the following for statement (Refund method):

```
for(int counter=(int)balance;counter>=10;counter-=10){
System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
balance-=10;
}
```

However, now that I've done that, 10,30,100 work but any other numbers i.e. 33,54,62 etc. don't work! Any suggestions?

Comment: you don't need the counter variable, try just using 'balance' itself in the for loop, should be simpler

Comment: How is it failing for multiples of 10? That is, what is it printing that it's not supposed to print, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify the question. **Your Refund method works fine.**

It suits your constrain "decrementing by 10 each time until there **is less than 10** credits remaining".
It won't suit if you change the constrain to **is less or equal 10**.

Here is my test, that works:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.refund(33);
    }

    public void refund(float balance) {
        System.out.println("You have selected the refund option:");

        for (int counter = (int) balance; counter >= 10; counter -= 10) {
            System.out.println("Balance: £" + balance);
            balance -= 10;
        }

        for (int counter = (int) balance; counter > 0; counter -= 1) {
            System.out.println("Balance: £" + balance);
            balance -= 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Balance: £" + balance);
    }
}
```

**I haven't modified the body of your method.**

Here is the output on 30 input:

```
You have selected the refund option:
Balance: £30.0
Balance: £20.0
Balance: £10.0
Balance: £0.0
```

And on 33:

```
You have selected the refund option:
Balance: £33.0
Balance: £23.0
Balance: £13.0
Balance: £3.0
Balance: £2.0
Balance: £1.0
Balance: £0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this. (not tested)

```
while(balance != 0) {
    System.out.println("The balance: " + balance);
    if(balance >= 10)
        balance -= 10;
    else
        balance--;
}
```

Comment: Nice piece of code. But it forgets to print the zero value. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int balance = 33;

        for (int counter = (int) balance; counter >= 10; counter -= 10) {
            System.out.println("Balance: £" + balance);
            balance -= 10;

            for(int c = (int) balance; c <= 10 && c>=0; c -= 1){
                System.out.println("Balance: £" + balance);
                balance -= 1;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to answer this question here are a few...

```
//Using While loops
public void refund(int balance){
    while(balance >= 10) {
        System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
        balance -= 10;
    }
    while(balance >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
        balance -= 1;
    }
}
// another possible while loop answer and my favorite
public static void refund(int balance){
    while(balance >= 0) {
        int decrement = (balance>=10?10:1);
        System.out.println("Balance: "+balance);
        balance -= decrement;
    }
}

// Using for loops
public void refundWithForLoops(int balance){
    for(balance=balance; balance >= 10; balance -=10) {
        System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
    }
    for(balance=balance; balance >= 0; balance--) {
        System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
    }
}

// with recursion
public static void refundWithRecursion(int balance){
    int decrement = (balance>=10?10:1);
    System.out.println("Balance: £"+balance);
    if(balance > 0) refundWithRecursion(balance-decrement);
}
```